# Can I upgrade my windows 10 home N edition to windows 10 pro without N edition?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1

I have windows 10 home N currently installed and activated. It says to upgrade your windows to pro N edition. I want to upgrade my computer from windows 10 home N to windows 10 pro but without N feature. I mean to say is:-

Windows 10 Home N ------------- Windows 10 pro
                     Upgrade

Without N or removal of N edition. Is it possible?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It can be done but you will need to change the Windows key using a windows 10 PRO key

Comment: -1 That is not true.

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar thing. Had Windows 7 pro, upgraded to windows 10 pro N, then wanted to go to windows 10 Pro. In addition, I had a new computer, so a reinstall was necessary anyways. Because it was a new computer, I knew that if I just installed windows on it, it would fail because all hardware was new etc.

On the forums, people suggested to connect to a live account so that the license would be attached to the live account, and one could transfer to a new pc. So I connected my system to the live account, swapped all hardware, but with the old ssd, booted up, windows was not activated. I was still using Windows 10 pro N at this point.

Contacted microsoft, they said I had to buy a new license because mine came from Windows 7.

I felt defeated and I wanted to go to Windows 10 Pro anyway, so I decided to reformat windows and install from scratch first, then buy a license on the new install. So I reinstalled windows to Windows 10 Pro, and windows activated it for me this time.

So the answer apparently is to reinstall windows, then it should work. Windows 10 pro and Windows 10 pro N are the same, with the exception that the N version is missing the media player codec pack.

Given that you are going from home to pro, and you must upgrade anyway, your problem is going to be getting rid of the N version. Unfortunately there is no way to migrate an existing install. Only a fresh install of windows will get you from Home N to Home.